# cannot configure mongodb and logstash

Tags: mongodb, logstash

Hi i am new logstash and as well as mongodb. I am not really sure if this is the right place to ask question or not, but i really need help. I have posted the same question in logstash-users google group as well, but i havent received and any answer. Further i have gone through all the posts at the google group but none of the solutions seem to be working.

i need to use mongodb for output so i ran the following command:

> ./plugin install contrib

After that i ran this command

> ./logstash agent --config logstash-shipper.conf

my logstash-shipper.conf is

> input {
>
> file  {
>
> > ```
> >     path => "/var/log/alternatives.log" 
> >      type => "syslog"
> > ```
>
> }
>
> }
>
> output  {
>        mongodb {
>
> > ```
> > codec => "plain"
> > collection => "logstash"
> > database => "mydb"
> > generateId => true
> > isodate => true
> > uri => "mongodb://localhost:27017/"
> > } }
> > ```

i get the error

```
Using milestone 2 input plugin 'file'. This plugin should be stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| An unexpected error occurred. This is probably a bug.   |
| You can find help with this problem in a few places:    |
|                                                         |
| * chat: #logstash IRC channel on freenode irc.          |
|     IRC via the web: http://goo.gl/TI4Ro                |
| * email: logstash-users@googlegroups.com                |
| * bug system: https://logstash.jira.com/                |
|                                                         |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
The error reported is: 
  Couldn't find any output plugin named 'mongodb'. Are you sure this is correct? Trying to load the mongodb output plugin resulted in this error: no such file to load -- logstash/outputs/mongodb
```

Comment: plugin install went through without any errors

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, the 1.4.2 distribution is slightly broken. The version name of the release is "1.4.2-modified" but the contrib version is still "1.4.2".

My workaround was to find ./lib/logstash/version.rb and change

> LOGSTASH_VERSION = "1.4.2-modified"

to

> LOGSTASH_VERSION = "1.4.2"

This allowed

> ./plugin install contrib

to work (i.e. my mongodb connection works now), and so far nothing else has broken. Interestingly enough, there's a note right in the version.rb file that says

```
# Note to authors: this should not include dashes because 'gem' barfs if
# you include a dash in the version string.
```

Oops.